# Login to wordpress using only a username - no password

Tags: php, wordpress

What's the best way to allow all wordpress users (except for the admin) to login using ONLY their username and no password.

My goal is to hide the password field all together both for registration and login.

I fully understand the security risk involved - but this is the functionality I am looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Each user is actually going to be entering a unique ID that we provide them with. That's why we don't need password because unique ID username is good enough. Data isn't sensitive at all as well.

Comment: What if when users registered the Password field was HIDDEN and it just was set to save THE SAME password for every single user. Then, the login page was rigged so again the password field was hidden and the same password was already entered so in the background it authenticates fully as if they had typed in their username and password even though they've only entered in their username... any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Jon but what if someone finds out the ID? This would be very easy to bruteforce, since you need to make sure they can remember the ID (so no long randomized strings), and there is only 1 factor instead of 2, so that makes the bruteforcing a lot faster. The second idea, filling in the same password for everyone, might be a good soolution if you really want this, but you should just stick to username and password..

Comment: anyway, how hard can it be for a user to enter a password for you to remove entering password?

Comment: Can you create the door for my house. Plz dont insert the lock, I don't need a lock....

Comment: I assure you I understand fully the security implications. I just want to know how to do it - I assure you it has a purpose.

Comment: @Jon I add an answer, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

A secure way to do this without any plugin is to implement [wp_set_auth_cookie()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie). It allows you to login users with their ID, the cookies can be store 14days max.

As others said, one password for everyone is not really an option, to much lack of security...